# Nautilus-actions not showing after reinstall

Tags: nautilus, nautilus-actions

I had Nautilus actions installed and configured with some custom actions, but due to some problems with the file explorer I had to compile Nautilus and install it again (version 3.14) now my custom actions disappeared but they still appear in the Nautilus actions configuration tool, I'm also missing the "open terminal" and "restore files" buttons from right click menu in the file explorer. I managed to get back those with `sudo apt-get install nautilus-open-terminal` but I'm still missing the Nautilus-actions button.

How can I restore this? I tried uninstalling and purging nautilus actions, then rebooting and reinstalling but no luck, also I tried deleting the actions in the config tool and adding some new ones but that doesn't work either.

I'm using Ubuntu 16.04

Also when I click the home button to open the file explorer all the desktop icons disappear

Comment: Could be this? https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2188306

Comment: I don't have that option in the gnome-tweak-tool (Ubuntu 16.04)

Comment: About nautilus-actions see [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/1031746/66509).