# Nautilus-actions in 18.04

Tags: nautilus, 18.04, nautilus-actions, nautilus-extensions

Nautilus-actions configuration tool, which was needed in order to have context menu actions in Nautilus doesn't seem available in the Software center in 18.04 LTS.

(This seemed reported as a bug [here](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/gedit/+bug/1756619) - but confusingly specifying `gedit` instead of the correct package.)

---

This is not a Gnome-Nautilus feature, I think, as suggested in a comment, because I have seen the same Nautilus version 3.26.3 in Solus Linux, and there Nautilus Actions is available and usable. Solus provides also in its repo a different program called *FileManager Configuration Tool*, run with `fma-config-tool`, which excepting the name is identical and can be used only alternatively to the Nautilus actions usual tool. But none of them is available in Ubuntu, no matter the repos enabled in software sources settings.

How can Nautilus Actions tool (or its alternative) be installed in Ubuntu 18.04 in order to get the custom context menu actions?

---

### Please do not answer by proposing other file managers.

**I know that there are file managers that have custom actions - in fact all those used by the main Linux systems and by the main systems of the Ubuntu family have them: Caja, Nemo, PCManFM, Thunar, Dolphin, Pantheon-Files. But I am not asking about that here.**

Comment: It seems that it is time to migrate to Caja, I'm seriously. GNOMErs [will remove everything from Nautilus and whole desktop](https://community.ubuntu.com/t/files-nautilus-v3-28-will-lose-the-desktop-icons-capability/3115/28?u=norbert)  someday.

Comment: @N0rbert - There is no problem for mu jumping from a file manager to another, only I tend to switch the desktop too on that occasion, and even the distro.  While this is not really the place for Linux philosophy, I am tempted to put a few words here. I think the simplification trend is good, on the condition that the features I need are not removed or are at least accessible by choice. (I am not at all gnome-only or gtk-only: I like KDE/Plasma and I also like Dolphin, but I find  that especially the latter needs cleaning and smoothing.)

Comment: @N0rbert - But this is **not a Gnome thing, but an Ubuntu-repo thing**: I am using the same version of Nautilus in Solus and there - as said in the question, I have not one, but two "Nautilus-actions" tools. - Anyway, I agree with you on this: Gnome is a bad choice for Ubuntu; I would have picked Budgie :) - but, as said above, this is a repo-related thing.

Comment: A second (more correctly filed) bug-report is present [here](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/nautilus/+bug/1768597).

Comment: @N0rbert - I cannot believe that I said Ubuntu should have selected Budgie (instead of Gnome)! - I meant KDE/Plasma of course: it is the most customizable, solid and (at least on my laptop)  light desktop (not far from Xfce in this respect), considering especially that it is the richest (in not only what it does, but also in what it could do).

Comment: @aplaice - that bug report is not about a problem with a package but about a package not being present. **How could the absence of a package be a bug?**  - I will edit my question accordingly.

Answer (score 32, accepted):

### Update 2021-04-23

For the latest Ubuntu 20.04 LTS (focal fossa) the below actions are not needed, the package `filemanager-actions` is located in *universe* [pocket](https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?suite=all&searchon=names&keywords=filemanager-actions). See [fresh answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/1138682/66509).

### Update 2018-05-31

[Daniel Marynicz](https://launchpad.net/%7Edaniel-marynicz) has [created PPA for Ubuntu 18.04 LTS](https://launchpad.net/%7Edaniel-marynicz/+archive/ubuntu/filemanager-actions) with Nautilus, Caja and Nemo-enabled packages. You can install them as usual:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:daniel-marynicz/filemanager-actions

sudo apt-get install filemanager-actions-nautilus-extension # Nautilus
sudo apt-get install filemanager-actions-caja-extension # Caja
sudo apt-get install filemanager-actions-nemo-extension # Nemo

sudo apt-get install filemanager-actions* # simply all filemanagers
```

After installation you can launch `fma-config-tool`.

---

### Initial consideration of the problem:

Modern version of Nautilus Actions ([`nautilus-actions` package in trusty (14.04 LTS), xenial (16.04 LTS), artful (17.10)](https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?suite=all&searchon=names&keywords=nautilus-actions)) are named as [FileManager Actions](https://git.gnome.org//browse/filemanager-actions) ([`filemanager-actions` package, it is not yet packaged in Debian and Ubuntu - see at repology.org](https://repology.org/metapackage/filemanager-actions/versions)).

If you do not want to compile packages by yourself - use links in the end of this answer.

So we can try to compile this package locally:

1. Install dependencies

   ```
    sudo apt-get install build-essential gnome-doc-utils intltool \
    libnautilus-extension-dev uuid-dev libxml2-dev libgtop2-dev rarian-compat
   ```

   **Note:** if you need to support all three file-managers you should install two additional packages before compilation with `sudo apt-get install libnemo-extension-dev libcaja-extension-dev`.
2. Download, extract, configure, make (otherwise, if you prefer the easy way: use the deb file from links at the end of answer)

   ```
    cd ~/Downloads
    wget https://download.gnome.org/sources/filemanager-actions/3.4/filemanager-actions-3.4.tar.xz
    tar -xf filemanager-actions-3.4.tar.xz
    cd filemanager-actions-3.4
    ./configure
    make -j5
   ```
3. Install package

   - Here standard way is to use

     ```
        sudo make install
     ```

     but this will not create deb-package (but you can remove fma with `sudo make uninstall`);
   - so using [`checkinstall`](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/CheckInstall) is better:

     ```
        sudo apt-get install checkinstall
        sudo checkinstall make install
        sudo apt-get install ./filemanager-actions_3.4-1_amd64.deb
     ```

After installation you will get new executable named  `fma-config-tool`, its window is named *FileManager-Actions Configuration Tool* and  looks like:

[image: fma-config-tool on Bionic]

---

Below is the link to compiled package:

- only Nautilus support - [download *filemanager-actions_3.4-1_amd64.deb*-package](https://mega.nz/#F!NZI20QTL!12ri294D7WgvAEiIJtBDsQ).

---

Comment: By default it puts everything in some awful sub-menu. Is there a way to override or bypass that

Comment: I'm on 18.04 and followed the instructions in the 18.04 section of your post - this does not seem to work. I can launch the program and add (and save) an item, but even after rebooting, nothing's showing up in my context menu.

Comment: @MrMesees Yes, just go on `Edit > Preferences` and disable `Create a root 'Nautilus-Actions' menu`

Comment: @FrancescoBoccardo I've done that via GUI. I want thinking more of having it done for me. TBH I'll probably git init my home folder and have it track changes, see if there is something SED / FS-level in my own home folder to manage.

Comment: If you are using ubuntu >= 18, then use filemanager actions. Refer this link for more details, [ubuntu-nautilus-actions](http://ubuntuhandbook.org/index.php/2019/01/install-nautilus-actions-ubuntu-18-04/)

Answer (score 3):

I've just upgraded from Ubuntu 16.04LTS to 18.04LTS, and find myself missing nautilus-actions as well. I tried installing caja-actions (as it doesn't depend on caja) on the off-chance it'd automatically work with nautilus, but unfortunately it does not.

According to the [github page for nautilus-actions](https://github.com/GNOME/nautilus-actions), it's been deprecated and renamed [FileManager-Actions](https://git.gnome.org/browse/filemanager-actions). I can't find a filemanager-actions package in Ubuntu 18.04, although there are source packages available at that 2nd link.

So our best shot might be to wait until we can't stand living without it any longer, then compile/tinker, depending on what state it's in.

---

**Update:**

I've just compiled/installed filemanager-actions 3.4 from [source](https://download.gnome.org/sources/filemanager-actions/3.4/) and it seems to be working fine with the stock Nautilus in Ubuntu 18.04 LTS :)

To compile it, I had to install the following extra packages:

```
intltool
gnome-doc-utils
libgtk-3-dev
libxml2-dev
uuid-dev
libgtop2-dev
libnautilus-extension-dev
```

libgtk-3-dev in particular will bring with it a lot of additional packages. You might want to use apt-get's --simulate option to keep track of exactly what's going to be installed before you go ahead with it - e.g.:

```
$ apt-get install --simulate intltool gnome-doc-utils libgtk-3-dev libxml2-dev uuid-dev libgtop2-dev libnautilus-extension-dev > cruft
```

I already had some development tools installed (gcc, make, etc). Installing the 'build-essential' package should get you everything you need.

Steps to compile and install filemanager-actions, after unpacking and cd'ing into the source directory, were:

```
$ ./configure --with-nautilus --disable-scrollkeeper
$ make
$ sudo make install-strip
```

After that I had to log out of GNOME, then back in, before filemanager-actions items appeared in the Nautilus right-click menu.

Comment: I have already mentioned FileManager-Actions in my question, which is present for other distros as an alternative to the old tool.

Comment: `caja-actions` depends on Caja:  it will not provide you with custom actions in Nautilus or other file manager, only in Caja.

Comment: Ah, sorry - by 'depend', I just meant in terms of package dependencies. Since the caja-actions package doesn't depend on the caja package, I figured I might as well try the experiment - though without great expectations :)

Comment: see https://repology.org/metapackage/filemanager-actions/versions

Comment: @N0rbert, thanks :) It looks like filemaneger-actions supports multiple file managers, incl. both caja and nautilus, but accidentally(?) slipped through the cracks and hasn't been picked up by debian/ubuntu. Here's the official GNOME [filemanager-actions source](https://download.gnome.org/sources/filemanager-actions/), which should be easy enough to compile...

Comment: @TimothyMusson I have updated my answer with method and link to the full-featured filemanager-actions package (supporting Nautilus, Caja and Nemo). Thank your for your idea!

Comment: @N0rbert, nice, thanks! :) BTW, I somehow managed to miss your update and did something similar - sorry for reinventing the wheel :)

Answer (score 1):

forget nautilus-actions, try nautilus-python, you can find examples inside usr/share/doc/python-nautilus/examples/.

or , you can try my script:
https://github.com/dwSun/utils/blob/master/Linux/open-terminator.py

Answer (score 0):

### Update 2023-04, [Actions For Nautilus](https://github.com/bassmanitram/actions-for-nautilus)

For Ubuntu 22.04 and higher, a new alternative has shown up on Github, and it seems to be actively maintained.

> An extension to the Gnome Files file manager (otherwise known as Nautilus) that allows you to add arbitrary actions to the Gnome Files selection context menu.
> This extension is a "replacement" for the now-defunct Nautilus file manager functionality of the filemanager/nautilus-actions project.

There is a .deb file and a [wiki](https://github.com/bassmanitram/actions-for-nautilus/wiki/Configuration-Examples) with an interesting topic:
"A less annoying New Document action".
Download the `config.json` file and put it in dir `~/.local/share/actions-for-nautilus`

On Ubuntu 20.04: installing the `.deb` file, won't work:

```
 actions-for-nautilus depends on python3 (>= 3.10.0); however:
 Version of python3 on system is 3.8.2-0ubuntu2.
 actions-for-nautilus depends on libjs-jquery (>= 3.5.0); however:
 Version of libjs-jquery on system is 3.3.1~dfsg-3
```

I am not sure - "actions for nautilus" might mess up your `apt update` workflows. At the next softwareupdate, nautilus packages might be marked as unclean. Thus `apt` with complain `The following packages have been kept back ...` - Please check yourself, carefully.