# How to get terminator to context menu in 18.04

Tags: 18.04, terminator, context-menu

While using previous LTS 16.xx I did have terminator in Nautilus context (right click) menu "Open with terminator" per steps done with nautilus-actions-config-tool.

Anyway after update to 18.04 terminator was removed from context menu and nautilus-actions-config-tool is not supported for 18.04. Any ideas how to get terminator back to context menu?

Comment: For your information `nautilus-actions` may be obtained from [links in this answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/1031746/66509). Then I hope you can set Terminator as you did in 16.04 LTS.

Answer (score 2):

1. Install Nautilus-actions in 18.04
   Launchpad user Daniel Marynicz has created PPA for Ubuntu 18.04 LTS with Nautilus. Follow those:
   `sudo add-apt-repository ppa:daniel-marynicz/filemanager-actions`
   `sudo apt-get install filemanager-actions-nautilus-extension`
   but you need use `fma-config-tool` to launch.
2. Add action to nautilus

[image: open in terminator]

[image: config]

after those steps, in the right-clicked menu it will show 'open in terminator' like this

[image: eg]

but it is still inconvenient！
 3. Set action to the top level in menu
open the config of the nautilus

[image: open config]

then, deselect "create root ..."

[image: deselect]

4. enjoy it

Comment: When I follow this exactly, "Open in Terminator" will not work with context menu from file selection. When I change 'Parameters' to '--working-directory=%d" without '/%b' that works but selection on directory open its parent directory. I couldn't find the solution for cover both problem. Did anyone solve this problem?

Comment: Solution found but not simple. Using 'Mimetypes' tab, you can filter by mime type. Use '--working-directory=%d' for '*' and NOT 'inode/directory', '--working-directory=%d/%b' for 'inode/directory'. I know it's linux but I think it should be easier than this.

Comment: worked for me, Ubuntu 20.04, thank you for explaining the parameters tab

Comment: After setting in Ubuntu 20.04 following this answer, you must reboot to activate it. It works perfectly!

Answer (score 0):

for ubuntu 22.04 LTS I used to [nautilus-open-any-terminal](https://github.com/Stunkymonkey/nautilus-open-any-terminal)
and it works perfectly.
[terminator in context menu](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sCvxp.png)