# What is an alternative for Nautilus Actions in MATE DE?

Tags: gnome, nautilus, 18.04, mate, caja

While using GNOME I have used `nautilus-actions` package to extend Nautilus functionality.

As we know it is [not available in Ubuntu 18.04 LTS Bionic Beaver](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1030940/nautilus-actions-in-18-04).

I like GNOME 2 successor - [MATE Desktop Environment](http://mate-desktop.org/) and its file-manager - Caja.

What is an alternative for Nautilus Actions in MATE DE?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The alternative is to use Caja and its Caja-actions:

```
sudo apt-get install caja-actions caja
```

You can setup anything in `caja-actions-config-tool`:

[image: Caja-Actions Configuration Tool]

The official documentation is built-in when installed and also [available in the github repository](https://github.com/raveit65/caja-actions/tree/master/docs/reference/html).

Also Caja has a lot of `caja-extensions`, so `caja-actions` is just one of them:

[image: Caja Extensions]

Available Extensions:

- **libgtkhash-properties-caja**
- **libcaja-seahorse**
- **Open terminal** - Open terminals from folders
- **libcaja-actions-tracker**
- **libcaja-actions-menu**
- **Wallpaper** - Allows to quickly set wallpaper
- **Python: caja-admin** - Python-caja extension
- **Python: folder-color** - Python-caja extension
- **Python: deja** - Python-caja extension
- **Python: caja-rename** - Python-caja extension
- **libeiciel-caja**
- **Atril properties** - Shows details for Atril documents
- **Engrampa** - Allows to create and extract archives
- **Send To** - Integrates email clients and Pidgin

Since we can not resurrect the Nautilus, the use of Caja seems appropriate.