# How to edit target path of broken symbolic link from GUI?

Tags: gui, filemanager, symbolic-link

Let's assume the following situation:

1. I have `file1` somewhere

   ```
   $ touch file1
   ```
2. I make symbolic link to `file1` as `symlink1`:

   ```
   $ ln -s file1 symlink1
   $ file symlink1 
   symlink1: symbolic link to file1
   ```
3. I rename `file1` to new name (now `symlink1` is broken)

   ```
   $ mv file1 file2
   $ file symlink1 
   symlink1: broken symbolic link to file1
   ```

After the last step the `symlink1`-link is broken.

I know that Midnight Commander has **File → Edit symlink** option, but it is terminal way:

[image: Edit symlink in Midnight Commander]

```
$ file symlink1 
symlink1: symbolic link to file2
```

and it is very useful if target and symlink are located in different file-systems and/or nested folders.

As far I can see Nautilus, Caja, Nemo, Thunar and Dolphin do not have this functionality.

**Update.** The most useful solution for me would be integration with Caja file-manager by [Caja-actions](https://askubuntu.com/a/1034213/66509). I use Caja on daily basis.

Comment: Delete the broken link and recreate it. That is how symbolic links work. They refer to a file name. If that name is missing or changes, the link breaks. You cannot directly change the target of an existing link.

Comment: @vanadium I understand how symbolic links work. But Midnight commander allows to change path of symbolic link's target. That is why I'm asking for GUI way.

Comment: MC will do the same behind the screens: delete and recreate the symlink. I do not know of a graphical file manager providing similar functionality. Perhaps the more power user oriented graphical dual pane file managers out there?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

## Edit Symbolic Link in Nautilus

### The script

To do this in Nautilus we need to create a script using:

```bash
mkdir -p ~/.local/share/nautilus/scripts
gedit ~/.local/share/nautilus/scripts/edit-link
```

Paste in the following:

```bash
#!/bin/bash

# NAME: edit-link
# PATH: $HOME/.local/share/nautilus/scripts
# DESC: Edit symbolic link
# CALL: Called from Nautilus file manager.
# DATE: August 18, 2018.

# strip new line char passed by Nautilus
FILENAME=$(echo $NAUTILUS_SCRIPT_SELECTED_FILE_PATHS | sed -e 's/\r//g')

# Multiple files can't be selected.
LINE_COUNT=$(wc -l <<< "$NAUTILUS_SCRIPT_SELECTED_FILE_PATHS")
LINE_COUNT=$((LINE_COUNT-1))

if [[ $LINE_COUNT > 1 ]] ; then
    zenity --error --text "Ony one file can be selected at a time! "
    exit 1
fi

# Object type must be "file..." (ie no directories, etc.)
if [ -d "${FILENAME}" ] ; then
    zenity --error --text "$FILENAME is a directory!";
    exit 1
else
    if [ -L "${FILENAME}" ]; then
        : # Bash noop
    else
        zenity --error --text "${FILENAME} is not a symbolic link!";
        exit 2
    fi
fi

NewLink=$(zenity --entry --text "Enter new symbolic link")
ln -sf "$NewLink" "${FILENAME}"

exit 0
```

and make it executable

```bash
chmod +x ~/.local/share/nautilus/scripts/edit-link
```

### Sample output

This is the test data used. The second last section shows the broken link. Then our script is run giving a new file name. The last section shows the new good link.

[image: Edit Link2]

### Sample screen

This is what the script looks like when you run it:

[image: edit link 1.png]

- Highlight a broken link with Nautilus
- Right click for context menu
- Select `Scripts`
- Select `edit-link`
- Enter new file name above and click <kbd>OK</kbd> button

## Edit Symbolic Link in Caja

The method is similar to Nautilus but with some Caja specifics. We should follow [GNOME2→MATE Migration guide](http://wiki.mate-desktop.org/migrating).

So we need create script in the `~/.config/caja/scripts`:

```bash
mkdir -p ~/.config/caja/scripts
cat > ~/.config/caja/scripts/edit-link << \EOF
#!/bin/bash

# NAME: edit-link
# PATH: $HOME/.config/caja/scripts
# DESC: Edit symbolic link
# CALL: Called from Caja file manager.
# DATE: August 19, 2018.

# strip new line char passed by Caja
FILENAME=$(echo $CAJA_SCRIPT_SELECTED_FILE_PATHS | sed -e 's/\r//g')

# Multiple files can't be selected.
LINE_COUNT=$(wc -l <<< "$CAJA_SCRIPT_SELECTED_FILE_PATHS")
LINE_COUNT=$((LINE_COUNT-1))

if [[ $LINE_COUNT > 1 ]] ; then
    zenity --error --text "Ony one file can be selected at a time! "
    exit 1
fi

# Object type must be "file..." (ie no directories, etc.)
if [ -d "${FILENAME}" ] ; then
    zenity --error --text "$FILENAME is a directory!";
    exit 1
else
    if [ -L "${FILENAME}" ]; then
        : # Bash noop
    else
        zenity --error --text "${FILENAME} is not a symbolic link!";
        exit 2
    fi
fi

NewLink=$(zenity --entry --text "Enter new symbolic link")
ln -sf "$NewLink" "${FILENAME}"

exit 0
EOF
```

and make it executable

```bash
chmod +x ~/.config/caja/scripts/edit-link
```

Then we can use this script from Caja Scripts drop-down menu.

Comment: Thank you! I added Caja related part as it trivial. I hope we have created very useful script.

Comment: @N0rbert Your edit reveals how similar writing a script in Caja File Manger is to Nautilus File Manager. Well done :) I did a second edit for language highlighting (prettify). Your use of `cat >` ... `<< \\EOF` instead of `gedit` is great for distro neutrality.

Answer (score 10):

I use thunar as my default file manager, and here is what I suggest to get a similar behavior like mc.

Create a simple shell script, and save it somewhere you like, for the demonstration purpose I saved it at my `$HOME`:

```bsh
#!/bin/bash
if [ -L "$1" ];
then
 new_address=$(zenity --entry)
 ln -sf "$new_address" "$1"
else
 zenity --error --text 'This is not a link'
fi
```

Add a new custom action which runs this script, for example in `thunar`:

[image]

Now I can right click on files and select 'relink', and it will asks for a new address for that link:

[image]

This is obvious that you have to install `zenity` package to use this script, I think you can manage to use it in different file managers.

Comment: Thanks! How do you think is it possible to use your script with [Caja-actions](https://askubuntu.com/a/1034213/66509) or maybe with [FileManager actions](https://askubuntu.com/a/1031746/66509)? I have never used them before but can give a try.

Comment: I never used Caja and from 11.04 I dropped Nautilus... so my knowledge is limited to things like this: [Integrating scripts in Nautilus to perform useful tasks](https://fedoramagazine.org/integrating-scripts-nautilus/) Which I have no idea whatever it works or not these days ...

Comment: @Ravexina thx, I use this on nautilus btw: https://sourceforge.net/p/scriptechocolor/git/ci/master/tree/ScriptEchoColor/bin.extras/sec.Symlink.Edit.NautilusScript.sh

Comment: Works perfect in Thunar. Thank you!

Comment: this does not seem to work when thunar opened in root -  I wonder if there is a way around this?