# Any file manager similar to xyplorer but for Linux?

Tags: filemanager

I find most of the GUI file browsers that I have come across pretty limited on options.

In xyplorer I really like:

- filters and power filters,
- multi-tabs,
- scripting.

I am not necessarily looking for xyplorer in Linux ( unless it exist :) ) but some good options to look at.

Comment: when viewing photos sure I use the Files filemanager however any power lifting on linux is better handled by crafting commands on the command line or automate into a bash script ... use the force Luke

Comment: [Directory Opus](https://www.gpsoft.com.au/), non-free, deserves an honorable mention here, too. AFAIK, there's [no Linux version available for it, either](https://resource.dopus.com/t/please-migrate-directory-opus-to-native-linux/19436) ;)

Comment: [XYplorer on Linux](https://www.xyplorer.com/xyfc/viewtopic.php?t=11058)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your question can have many answers.

Personally I prefer to use Caja from [MATE DE](http://mate-desktop.org/) (GNOME 2 fork), below I give illustrations of its functionality:

- filters

  1. Filters for current view is done by clicking <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>S</kbd> (or selecting *Edit* → *Select Items Matching...*):

     [image: select items matching]
  2. Other way to filter items is to use search function by clicking special button named *Search documents and folders by name*:

     [image: search]
- multi-tabs

  1. Tabs are created by clicking <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd> (or selecting *File*→*New Tab*):

     [image: tabs]
  2. You can use split view with <kbd>F3</kbd> (or selecting *View*→*Extra Pane*):

     [image: extra pane]

     As it shown above this feature is very useful with *Copy To* or *Move To* actions.
- scripting

  Scripting is done by

  1. using Caja Actions scripts. This feature is installed with `caja-actions` package and configurable from Caja-Actions Configuration Tool (`caja-actions-config-tool`). See [other answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/1034213/66509) for details.
  2. using Caja Python extensions. This feature is installed with `caja-extensions-common` package. The user scripts should be placed in `~/.local/share/caja-python/extensions`. See [other answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/1034213/66509) for details.

Some additional remarks:

- By default its *Side Pane* shows *Places*, but you can switch it to *Tree* view:

  [image: Tree view]
- You can combine *Places* view in side pane with *List View* of main panel to show directory tree:

  [image: List view with three]
- The *Extra Pane* (with <kbd>F3</kbd>) allows to combine views - for example *List View* in the left and *Icon View* in the right:

  [image: List View + Icon View]

---

If you are willing to try Caja you can install it with `sudo apt-get install caja`.

Comment: Caja is no where near the caliber of XYplorer. Nothing comes close to XYPlorer in terms of features and functionalities. Where is the multi-rename, the sophisticated search, the preview pane, and many others? I tried Caja and it left me cold. And what's the point of "Combine views - for example List View in the left and Icon View in the right"? That's pointless. They could've changed it to Preview which is much useful

Answer (score 1):

Since you can run **bash** shell scripts from there, being able to to add items of your choice to the file context menu in **thunar** means you can add virtually any new functions to **thunar** that you want, including the multi-rename, sophisticated search, and preview pane that https://askubuntu.com/users/1143020/maximo-dakila is concerned about.  You're not limited to the functions that originally came with **thunar.**  Useful tools for those shell scripts that you run from **thunar** are **zenity** and **notify-send.**  In particular, **zenity** can be used to build new custom menus of your choice that get called up by a new item you've added to the **thunar** file context menu.

Details on how to customize the **thunar** file context menu are at: [How to customize files context menu in Xubuntu XFCE Thunar file manager?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/18367/how-to-customize-files-context-menu-in-xubuntu-xfce-thunar-file-manager)

Answer (score 0):

Actually...with the help of WINE you can run XYplorer under Linux! ;)
(see [this](https://www.xyplorer.com/xyfc/viewtopic.php?t=11058) thread)