# Create custom mount/unmount entry for nemo/nautilus "devices"

Tags: mount, nautilus, devices, nemo, sshfs

`sshfs` mounts are shown under "devices" in Nemo and Nautilus, together with this eject/unmount button.

[image]

The eject/unmount button never works. When I go to the terminal and `sshfs` something into my home dir (for which I needn't `sudo`), the unmount button still has "permission denied". This has been the same for all Ubuntu versions since 16.04.

When I manually unmount the sshfs mount, the entire device entry disappears from the list, so I cannot re-mount it just by clicking on it.

**Is there a way to manually add a "device", run a custom mount script when I click on it, and run a custom unmount script when I click on the eject/unmount button?**

Answer (score 2):

SSHfs unmount problem is known (see [bug 254171 for Nautilus](https://bugs.launchpad.net/bugs/254171) and [bug 1763033 for Caja](https://bugs.launchpad.net/bugs/1763033)).

You can mount some network shares (SSH, FTP, SMB/CIFS) with help of GVFS by creating *Bookmarks* for them (something like `smb://1.1.1.1/public_share`). Such mounts will not require root/superuser access. From terminal you can access their files in `/run/user/1000/gvfs/smb-share:server=localhost,share=public_share` (or similar).

For custom scripts you can try to use Nautilus Action (or FileManager Actions). See [this Q&A](https://askubuntu.com/a/1031746/66509) for details.

Answer (score 2):

An approach that circumvents the bug mentionned in the answer of NOrbert would be to declare the mount in /etc/fstab. Include your sshfs mount in /etc/fstab, and add the options `noauto` and `users`.

- `noauto` causes the mount not to be carried out during the execution of fstab. Only the information needed for the mount is being declared to the system.
- `users` declares that the mount can be performed by any user of the system. Use the option `user=<uid>` if you want to allow the mount only to a specific user.

To have the mounts appear in nautilus, you need to define the mount point under the /media folder or within your home folder.

Comment: This sounds good, except I would like to be able to launch a custom script. E.g. for mounting a ZFS dataset with an encryption key that is in the keyring of the user. Is there a hook that can do this?

Comment: Try it first. It may exactly behave as you expect, without the need for a custom script.

Comment: I can't figure out how to specify a key as stored in the user keyring.

Comment: Search "mount sshfs" to learn how to mount and pass credentials.